# Why do I get parse error on input "isFileEnd" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Below is my haskell code.

```
readTableFile :: String -> (Handle -> IO a) -> IO [a]
readTableFile file func = do 
      fileHandle <- withFile file ReadMode (\handle -> do  
        contents <- readDataFrom handle     
        putStr contents)
      where readDataFrom fileHandle = do 
        isFileEnd <- hIsEOF fileHandle
        if isFileEnd 
            then
                return ("")
            else
                do
                    info <- hGetLine fileHandle
                    putStrLn $ func info
                    readDataFrom fileHandle
```

But I get an error:

```
error: parse error on input ‘isFileEnd’
    |
270 |         isFileEnd <- hIsEOF fileHandle
    |         ^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't know why. Please help me

Comment: looks like an indentation issue. Try indenting that line and all subsequent ones so that the start is further right than the start of `readDataFrom` on the preceding line.

Comment: Don't return the handle given to you from inside `withFile`. It will already be closed (and so invalid) by the time `withFile` finishes. (You aren't making this mistake... yet.)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple things going on that are contributing here.  As the commenter above pointed out, when you get parse errors that look surprising, spacing is always the first thing to look for.  However, we could take a look at   a couple things that are contributing here:

1. Your `readTableFile` is really just one line long.  You've got a `do` block in which the only thing you do is to assign to `fileHandle` the value from inside the IO monad that `withFile` ran in.  Aside from the fact that `withFile` is going to return an IO action from your handler (and not the file handle that your naming might imply) your function isn't actually returning an IO action.  Let's clean up some:

```
readTableFile file func = do
    withFile file ReadMode (\handle -> do  
        contents <- readDataFrom handle     
        putStr contents)
          where readDataFrom fileHandle = do 
            isFileEnd <- hIsEOF fileHandle
            [...]
```

2. Now we're returning the right type, but you're still going to get a parse error from the `isFileEnd <-` assignment.  Now that we've cleaned up, you can get your code to compile by moving that (and subsequent lines) to the right of the first character of the `readDataFrom` declaration:

```
          where readDataFrom fileHandle = do 
                 isFileEnd <- hIsEOF fileHandle
                 [...]
```

Your top level do is still redundant, but you'll be past your immediate problems.

Comment: I'd emphasize that this is really only getting you past your immediate problems, and that your code is probably still not going to do what you think it is, but since this is probably homework, I'd prefer to use the smallest nudge possible.